# Mac+iPhone: calendar + reminders (or tasks)

Tags: iphone, calendar, reminders, google-calendar

I'm trying to make something work for both Mac and iPhone and I'm open to any solution that works on both.

Problem: I have a work Google account with my work events, and I need to use either my personal Apple or Google account for events and reminders (Apple)/tasks (Google).

I need to be able to see events AND reminders/tasks of both accounts at the same time, on the phone and MacBook. On the phone I could just use Google Calendar and ditch Apple Reminders in favor of Google Tasks. The problem is that there's no Google Calendar app for desktop.

I can't use Apple Calendar because it doesn't show reminders or tasks, as far as I know. I can't add the web version of Google Calendar as a Chrome app because I can't use two accounts at once.

Any idea what to do?

Comment: So use Apple Reminders.  Does it no longer import Google Tasks?

Comment: Apple reminders don't show in apple calendar, right? I need to see both events AND reminders/tasks/todos on the same place, so I can see the time I'm supposed to be doing the task